# MS compiler still requires variable declaration must be put to the very beginning of C functions?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, variables, declaration

Is that true? I read the help document and cannot find options to enable this feature. 
It is so bothering while porting some c99 compatible source code to MS compiler.

BR, Ruochen

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Microsoft's compiler does not support most C99 features.  Some more support is coming in the future, [supposedly](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/06/c99-acknowledged-at-last-as-microsoft-lays-out-its-path-to-c14/).